# cmake find boost library Mac

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, osx-yosemite

I have searched the forums, and found relevant material, but I cannot apply any solution to this problem (most threads were applicable to windows/linux). My default cmake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(01___Shared_Pointers)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    Point.cpp
    Point.hpp
    TestSharedPtr101.cpp)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ENDIF()

add_executable(01___Shared_Pointers ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

On my machine, boost is located at "Macintosh HD/opt/local/include/boost". I believe I am using version 1.57, which I installed via MacPorts. Is integration even possible on a Mac? Or am I wasting my time? Many thanks.

Comment: Sure it is possible. Your CMakeLists.txt does not contain any indication of using Boost. Can you add this part of the code? Maybe you have to pass cmake the path to your boost installation, either via the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or via BOOST_ROOT.

Comment: Thanks....I updated my CMakeLists.txt in my original thread...does that look correct? I don't trust myself guessing with CMake.

Comment: Ok, when you configure with cmake, does it find Boost or not? It is best to delete your build directory first.

Comment: As far as I know, it found Boost. My program compiles and runs. But what is "-DHAS_BOOST"? I cannot find any documentation on this syntax.

Comment: It adds -DHAS_BOOST to compiler flags. The compiler interprets the stuff following -D as a preprocessor variable. In your case, you can check inside the C++ code with `#ifdef HAS_BOOST`. You also pass -DHAS_BOOST=1 or some other value.

Comment: Thanks for your help...just so you know I'm trying this on CLion EAP so I had double the concern.